# Make new array with data from another array column with .map() function in vuejs and laravel

Tags: arrays, vue.js

This is my array:

```
[
 {product: "banana", quantity: "0", price: "32"}
 {product: "tomato", quantity: "1", price: "45"}
 {product: "mango", quantity: "2", price: "56"}
]
```

Now i want to make new array with products value like this:

```
["banana","tomato","mango"]
```

using `.map()` function or whatever.

Comment: Why not use, yourArray.map(x=>x.product) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
const itemList = [
 {product: "banana", quantity: "0", price: "32"}
 {product: "tomato", quantity: "1", price: "45"}
 {product: "mango", quantity: "2", price: "56"}
]

console.log(itemList.map(item => item.product))
```

Comment: ok i'll try this

Answer (score 1):

Using LODASH

```
const itemList = [
 {product: "banana", quantity: "0", price: "32"},
 {product: "tomato", quantity: "1", price: "45"},
 {product: "mango", quantity: "2", price: "56"}
]

const items = _(itemList)
  .map('product')
  .value();

alert(items)
```